# Single Farm with ForeFront AUG or 2 Serparate Farm to secure intranet/extranet Farm?

Tags: farm-solution, topology, farm-setup

We're planning of setting up a two separate farm (internet farm and intranet/extranet farm) for security purposes. My question is that, if we use the Edge Topology (using the ForeFront AUG) is't okey to setup now a single farm and use the AAM (Zone) to separate the internet and intranet/extranet site instead of 2 two separate farm?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely read this as described by Microsoft 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc263513(v=office.14).aspx

--

Considering the security requirements, you will typically need separate farms one on the DMZ and another in the corporate network perimeter, when you are publishing content from an internal authoring farm and making it available through content deployment on the consuming DMZ farm.

[image]

Incase, your security concerns are limited only upto choice of alternate authentication mechanisms for partners/client users outside your corporate domain , you can go for a Claims or FBA based extended web application leveraging AAM. In this case a single farm behind UAG should address your requirements provided you have correctly opened the ports to your internal network for the web applications hosted in SharePoint.

Comment: yes, we're limited in terms of budget capacity so implementing the "Split back-to-back optimized for content publishing" topology is not possible. Also, if we choose not to implement the external topology, meaning only internet and intranet, do we still need to use AUG for security purposes?

Comment: Your sharepoint external topology is not dependent on UAG. SharePoint external web applications can be used with AAM to seperate Internal sites from external ones along with different auth mechanisms. UAG is a network layer software which addresses firewall level routing and forwarding. You can achieve the same with a Cisco infrastructure and SharePoint.